# How to fully justify the whole document?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, hyphenation

I want to remove the hyphenation but I don't want to leave spaces in the end of the line due to the removal of the first letters of the last word.
So, I want to make variable spaces between the words to fill the gap let by the removed letters.

My document classe is "report".

Thank you.

Comment: `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`.  You may be forced to also use `\sloppy` to avoid overrunning margins, though `hyphenat` may already do something comparable.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\textwidth=4in
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```